Alphabetize a List of Names in Python from a list of inputs without being able to use any sort of sort function
I do not have a lot of programing experience, but I've been trying to get a program working were from a number of inputs it can alphabetize a list and print it going up and down without showing any of the steps it does to get to the conclusion. and can't use any sort function in it.
def orgianlAlphabeticalList(): 
    for amountInList in range(len(allInputsInLists)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(amountInList):
            if allInputsInLists[i] > allInputsInLists[i+1]:
                allInputsInLists[i], allInputsInLists[i+1] = allInputsInLists[i+1], allInputsInLists[i]
                print(allInputsInLists)

This is my function for alphabetizing the list I have not a lot of programing experience

You have not actually asked a question here.  If this code is not doing what you want, then show us what it actually does and explain how that is different from what you expected.

So basically you're being asked to write a sort from scratch.  A noble goal for learning.  What research have you done into sorting methods?

What you have written is a sort function which, apparently, you're not able to use. So, rather pointless really

Your function is fine. What you did is a kind of bubble sort implementation, that needs to be fixed.
It is a O(N ^ 2) time complexity method for sorting. It is not the best one. But the fact that you could come up with that, is pretty good.
def orgianlAlphabeticalList(allInputsInLists):
    for amountInList in range(len(allInputsInLists) - 1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(amountInList):
            if allInputsInLists[i] > allInputsInLists[i + 1]:
                allInputsInLists[i], allInputsInLists[i + 1] = allInputsInLists[i + 1], allInputsInLists[i]
    return allInputsInLists


sample_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape']
sorted_list = orgianlAlphabeticalList(sample_list)
print(sorted_list)


Prints

['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'grape', 'grape', 'orange',
'orange']

Note

There is a way to optimize this method.

What if in your second loop, it would never go inside this if allInputsInLists[i] > allInputsInLists[i+1]:?

In that case, we can for instance add a counter or a flag right before the second loop and then at the end of second loop, we check to see if we ever had any swap? If not, the list is "partially" sorted.


def orgianlAlphabeticalList(allInputsInLists):
    for amountInList in range(len(allInputsInLists) - 1, 0, -1):
        count = 0
        for i in range(amountInList):
            if allInputsInLists[i] > allInputsInLists[i + 1]:
                allInputsInLists[i], allInputsInLists[i + 1] = allInputsInLists[i + 1], allInputsInLists[i]
                count += 1
        if count == 0:
            break
    return allInputsInLists


sample_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape']
sorted_list = orgianlAlphabeticalList(sample_list)
print(sorted_list)


Prints

['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'grape', 'grape', 'orange',
'orange']


Note

There is one more thing. What if we had "App", "Apple", "Apps", "Applicant", or "Application" in the list?

Let's modify our algorithm for that and also properly name our variables:


def orgianl_alphabetical_list(words):
    def swap(i, j):
        words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]

    def check_every_char(s1, s2):
        length = min(len(s1), len(s2))
        for i in range(length):
            if s1[i] > s2[i]:
                return True
            elif s1[i] < s2[i]:
                return False
        return len(s1) > len(s2)

    for i in range(len(words)):
        no_swap = False
        for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
            if check_every_char(words[i], words[j]):
                swap(i, j)
                no_swap = True
        if no_swap == False:
            break

    return words


sample_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'apple',
               'orange', 'grape', "App", "Apple", "Apps", "Applicant", "Application"]
sorted_list = orgianl_alphabetical_list(sample_list)
print(sorted_list)


Prints

['App', 'Apple', 'Applicant', 'Application', 'Apps', 'apple', 'apple',
'banana', 'banana', 'grape', 'grape', 'orange', 'orange']

Note

We have a simple swap function, that performs our swap operations.
We have a check_every_char function, as a helper method to help us sort, "App", "Apps" and so on.

